# C# VS2015 Express: The primary reference ... could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, com, .net-2.0

I have a C# "MyAssembly" .NET 2.0 assembly referenced by a C# "MyAssemblyTester" .NET 2.0 exe.
I am using Visual Studio Express 2015.
Both projects compile and work fine.

If I add to "MyAssembly" project a reference to a very old OCX (before year 2000: Teechart Pro Activex 4.0.1.7, but I had the same problem with other old COM DLL components) and recompile, the "MyAssembly" project compiles and link fine, but I have a lot of errors for "MyAssemblyTester" like this:

```
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MyAssemblyTester, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "MyAssembly" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "MyAssembly" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "MyAssembly" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "MyAssembly" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "MyAssembly" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "MyAssembly" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "MyAssembly" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "MyAssembly" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "MyAssembly" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "MyAssembly" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "Accessibility, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "MyAssembly" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System.Deployment, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "MyAssembly" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "MyAssembly" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System.Data.SqlXml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "MyAssembly" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "MyAssembly" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
```

If I change the target framework for both "MyAssembly" and "MyAssemblyTester" to .NET 4.0, the problem is solved. However, due to backward compatibility, I want to have a .NET 2.0 target framework.

I think that the source of the problem is that the Interop assemblies (AxInterop.TeeChart.dll and Interop.TeeChart.dll) generated by VS2015 target .NET 4.0.
Indeed ILSpy output for AxInterop.TeeChart.dll is:

```
// AxInterop.TeeChart, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

// Global type: <Module>
// Architecture: AnyCPU (64-bit preferred)
// Runtime: .NET 4.0

using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: AxHost.TypeLibraryTimeStampAttribute("05/13/2009 16:17:54")]

// System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// Interop.TeeChart, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
// System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

And Interop.TeeChart.dll is similar.

Some pieces of the detailed build log (1> is MyAssembly and 2> MyAssemblyTester):

```
...
1>Using "ResolveComReference" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "ResolveComReference"
1>  Creating new cache file at "obj\x86\Debug\MyAssembly.csproj.ResolveComReference.cache".
1>  Adding a matching tlbimp reference for the aximp reference "AxTeeChart".
1>  Resolving COM reference for item "stdole" with a wrapper "primary".
1>  Determining dependencies of the COM reference "stdole".
1>  Resolved COM reference for item "stdole": "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\stdole\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\stdole.dll".
1>  Resolving COM reference for item "AxTeeChart" with a wrapper "primaryortlbimp".
1>  Determining dependencies of the COM reference "AxTeeChart".
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools\TlbImp.exe C:\Windows\SysWOW64\teechart.ocx /namespace:TeeChart /machine:X86 /out:obj\x86\Debug\Interop.TeeChart.dll /sysarray /transform:DispRet /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\ABCD\abcdSDK\DLL\x86\abcdsdk.dll" /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Windows.Forms.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll /reference:C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\stdole\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\stdole.dll 
1>  Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Type Library to Assembly Converter 4.6.81.0
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>  
1>  TlbImp : Type library imported to C:\repSVN\Prod2NCG2\prodmspeqspcp\trunk\src\MyAssembly\obj\x86\Debug\Interop.TeeChart.dll
1>  Resolved COM reference for item "AxTeeChart": "obj\x86\Debug\Interop.TeeChart.dll".
1>  Resolving COM reference for item "AxTeeChart" with a wrapper "aximp".
1>  Determining dependencies of the COM reference "AxTeeChart".
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools\AxImp.exe C:\Windows\SysWOW64\teechart.ocx /out:obj\x86\Debug\AxInterop.TeeChart.dll /rcw:obj\x86\Debug\Interop.TeeChart.dll 
1>  Generated Assembly: C:\repSVN\Prod2NCG2\prodmspeqspcp\trunk\src\MyAssembly\obj\x86\Debug\AxInterop.TeeChart.dll
1>  Resolved COM reference for item "AxTeeChart": "obj\x86\Debug\AxInterop.TeeChart.dll".
1>Done executing task "ResolveComReference".
1>Done building target "ResolveComReferences" in project "MyAssembly.csproj".
...
...
...
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "MyAssembly" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "MyAssembly" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
...
...
...
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "MyAssembly" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "MyAssembly" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
2>  Primary reference "mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
2>      Resolved file path is "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll".
2>      Reference found at search path location "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll".
2>      This reference is not "CopyLocal" because it's a prerequisite file.
2>      The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v2.0.50727".
2>  Primary reference "System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
2>      Resolved file path is "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll".
2>      Reference found at search path location "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
2>          For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
2>          Considered "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.winmd", but it didn't exist.
2>      This reference is not "CopyLocal" because it's a prerequisite file.
2>      The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v2.0.50727".
2>      Resolved file path is "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll".
...
...
...
2>      Reference found at search path location "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
2>          For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
2>          Considered "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.winmd", but it didn't exist.
2>      This reference is not "CopyLocal" because it's a prerequisite file.
2>      The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v2.0.50727".
2>Done executing task "ResolveAssemblyReference".
....
```

How could I manually change the target framework for Interop assemblies?
Maybe I need to change the AxImp and TlbImp path or some of their options?

Any other idea?

Thank you

Comment: Hmm, no, that class library project does not target 2.0.  An accident with a .regx file is possible, but none of its dependencies are compatible with 2.0.  This is pebkac.

Comment: @HansPassant Are you referring to MyAssembly? Its properties have Target framework = .NET Framework 2.0. As I said, when set to .NET Framework 4.0 everything is OK, but I need .NET 2.0. Any basic suggestion for the pebkac is very much appreciated.

Comment: Just switch the build verbosity to Detailed so you can double-check assumptions and see what reference assemblies are actually being used by the compiler.  Check where they came from, run ildasm.exe to look at their manifest.

Comment: I have same problem with VS 2017, MSBuild 15. The app is .NET 3.5, and every dll is build correctly - except introp, which is build as 4.0. I was not able to find root cause. My colleagues use the same versions of SW (mentioned above) but it works OK for them. I work-around the issue by creating .bat file that copies "correct" version of interop DLL to necessary bin/debug folder after rebuild. I have the "correct" version built on some other machine. This looks tom like bug in VS/MSBuild/Compiler or some of its parameters passed internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved installing "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1", then adding to "Post-build event command line":

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\TlbImp.exe" C:\Windows\SysWOW64\teechart.ocx /namespace:TeeChart /machine:X86 /out:$(TargetDir)\Interop.TeeChart.dll /sysarray /transform:DispRet /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\ABCD\abcdSDK\DLL\x86\abcdsdk.dll" /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Windows.Forms.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll /reference:C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\stdole\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\stdole.dll
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\AxImp.exe" C:\Windows\SysWOW64\teechart.ocx /out:$(TargetDir)\AxInterop.TeeChart.dll /rcw:$(TargetDir)\Interop.TeeChart.dll
```

(copied the commands from the detailed build log, changed the path for AxImp and TlbImp to the 3.5 SDK and the output paths for the Interop assemblies from obj\x86\Debug to $(TargetDir)).

I wonder whether there is a cleaner solution.